# What does the new parameter 'reference' do in sendTrytes?

Tags: iri-legacy-api, java

[PR #112](https://github.com/iotaledger/iota-java/pull/112) added a second parameter, namely `String reference`, to [`GetTransactionsToApproveResponse`](https://github.com/iotaledger/iota-java/commit/e2df95bd683611fe3c6d129c877f855554807d52#diff-a36a05dae93cbc91d05f82b68162076f).

This parameter can also be set in `sendTrytes`. The Javadoc there says

> Hash of transaction to start random-walk from, used to make sure the
>   tips returned reference a given transaction in their past.

When and why would I set this parameter, instead of leaving it `null`?

---

```
/**
 * Facade method: Gets transactions to approve, attaches to Tangle, broadcasts and stores.
 *
 * @param trytes             The trytes.
 * @param depth              The depth.
 * @param minWeightMagnitude The minimum weight magnitude.
 * @param reference          Hash of transaction to start random-walk from, used to make sure the tips returned reference a given transaction in their past.
 * @return Transactions objects.
 * @throws ArgumentException is thrown when invalid trytes is provided.
 */
public List<Transaction> sendTrytes(final String[] trytes, final int depth, final int minWeightMagnitude, final String reference) throws ArgumentException;
```

Comment: I can think of two reasons: 1) when you want to promote another transaction with your transaction/bundle. 2) when you try to spend a balance you received but which was not confirmed, to make sure that other transaction confirms too before/when your transaction confirms.

Comment: Thx. To 1: What does 'promote' mean in this context. To 2: Okay, understood. This translates to payments within sub-tangles.

Comment: Promote = reference an old transaction by a more recent one to increase the chance of it (or more precisely, both of them) getting confirmed by the coordinator.